# heroku removes part of file url of aws s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I use laravel project to upload some images to AWS S3 storage and I use heroku service to deploy my project.

The images uploaded successfully but the url returned like `https://.s3.amazonaws.com/9/conversions/phpGTebCB-thumb.jpg`

However, it should be like this `https://MY_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/9/conversions/phpGTebCB-thumb.jpg`

So the image didn't display successfully.

Of course, the upload system is working correctly on my localhost.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask]. You might also want to learn about [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem

I forget to add optional property to `config/medialibrary.php` at this line `'domain' => 'https://'.env('AWS_BUCKET', 'MY_BUCKET').'.s3.amazonaws.com',`